# getRemoteUser() after successful login

Tags: http, servlets

I am trying to write my login page. After a successful login how can I get the user id in request.getRemoteUser() for my rest APIs that I have written using resteasy.

Comment: Are you trying to use `request.getRemoteUser()` in a resteasy method? It's not very clear...

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks